# Developing and deploying step functions with Terraform - a better development experience?

Tags: terraform, aws-step-functions

I want to ask whether anyone has experience using Terraform to deploy step functions?

I'm experimenting with step functions and need to deploy to multiple environments in a repeatable and auditable manner. I develop my step functions in the AWS console (Workflow Studio) in my sandbox environment but eventually I need to deploy them to my higher envs.

Currently this is done by exporting the step function from the sandbox environment as JSON and putting that into a Terraform module that is used to deploy the solutions. This poses a problem because the sandbox step function is invoking a lambda that lives in the sandbox environment while the other envs have their own lambda deployed of course, which the step function should be calling.

To solve that problem, the step function JSON is actually a template file where the ARNs for the lambdas are replaced with a variable which is then expanded per environment with the appropriate value.

But all this makes for a terrible development experience. Every time a change is made to the step function, I have to export the JSON, copy it into the Terraform module and replace all the sandbox ARNs with the correct template variables.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to streamline this? Are step functions only good for ad-hoc data processing where repeatable and auditable deployments are not needed or am I missing some obvious solution here?

Comment: Hmm., You didn't use `templates` to create `json` files on the file? I haven't used `aws` myself but just thinking more from templating perspective to generate json files..

Comment: Im not very familiar with the workings of Terraform, but it just hooks into Cloud Formation right? If so there are plenty of ways to make Cloud Formation parameterized do a search for parameters for cloud formation templates. Terraform should have a method for adjusting those on the fly - alternatively, CDK is aws Infrastructure as Code library, which can very much do all this (pretty sure terraform can as well mind you)

Answer (score 0):

As it was already stated in the comments you can consider [SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/overview.html) as well as [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification.html) or [Serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/).

Other links to consider:

- [Serverless step functions project](https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-step-functions)
- [SAM step functions
  document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-state-machine-using-sam.html)